# How can I define a generic store factory with Pinia in Vue 3 while maintaining types?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

I'm storing a few resources in my Vue app, let's say...

```
type Foo {
  id: string
  // ... properties
}

type Bar {
  id: string
  // ... properties
}
```

I would like to create Pinia stores for these types, but I want to do this using the factory method as I have quite a few more types than Foo and Bar. I have tried to use something like...

```
export const kindStoreFactory<T extends {'id': string}>(
    name: string
) => {
    return defineStore(name, () => {
        const collection = ref({} as Map<string, T>)

        return { collection }
    })
}

export const useFooStore = () => kindStoreFactory<Foo>('foo')
```

However when I utilize this code in a component, or another store, the collection property is not found on the store object:

```
...
const fooStore = useFooStore()

fooStore.collection // <-- undefined
```

I'm not all that strong with Typescript, and I'm assuming this has something to do with wrapping defineStore() and the types not returning "cleanly?"

Any insight provided would be wonderful. Thank you!